# Hiding content type from "New" menu, hides it in edit form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, content-type, modern-experience

I've added content types to a list, and I want only 1 to appear on the "new" menu button.  To do this, I've set only the single type to be visible on the "new" menu, and thus it is the default type.  Well by hiding the others, they no longer even show up in the "Content Type" selection drop down in the item form.

This is *not* how I remember things working in recent memory.  I'd expect all content types to be selectable in the item form.  This is all in "Modern" SharePoint Online.  Am I forgetting something or has this behavior changed?

Comment: How do you set only the single type to be visible on the "new" menu?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/100449)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/100449)

Comment: How do you set only the single type to be visible on the "new" menu?

Comment: @LisaChenMSFT I did so by deselecting all other content types from the "appears on the new menu" check boxes in the list settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deselecting all other content types from the "appears on the new menu" check boxes in the list settings, it is by designer that they no longer show up in the "Content Type" selection drop down in the item form.

Comment: A bit counter intuitive, but it is what it is.  I figured the "new" menu setting to be controlling what can be selected on initial creation, but after that all other content types are fair game.